# Adding to a list in python with + makes a new list with different id()

Tags: python

I am new to python and can't figure out why adding to a list with the + sign creates a new list with a different id but using .append adds elements to a list at the original id.

The list and its id:

```
>>> list = [1,2,3]
>>> id(list)
140619372689160
```

Adding to the list using + makes a new list:

```
>>> list + [4,5,7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Print list again does not include addition:

```
>>> print(list)
[1, 2, 3]
```

The address of the list is the same:

```
>>> id(list)
140619372689160
```

Why does adding to the list create a new list and not add to the list at that address?

Comment: you're not assigning the new list to `list` when you perform the addition. you need to declare a new variable, or use list again. BTW, don't use `list`, it's a builtin

Comment: `2 + 2` adds two integers to make a new integer. `[2] + [2]` adds two lists to make a new list. Why would `+` modify its operands? You can use `.extend()` to add all elements of a sequence to a list.

Answer (score -1):

what you want to do is :

```
list += [4,5,7]
```

or

```
list = list + [4,5,7]
```

like that you assign the new created list to your actual list

quick example:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l += [4,5,6]
print(l) # returns [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Those two are *not* equivalent. The former mutates the list in place, the latter created a new list

Comment: i don't think i mentioned any equivalence did I ? but thanks for pointing that out anyway